# How to create a table like this?

Tags: tables

[image: table]

It is simple, but I just cannot figure out how to draw that cross...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the setting `{c|ccccc}` if you put the `|` character, it will draw the vertical and then between the lines you want to put `\hline` for the horizontal one. Thats it.